# how can I create the regex of this string replacement;

Tags: regex

I want to replace the String :  `nf.format(xxx ddhgshg jjhjhsss)` with the `nf.format(0)`, I mean I need the regex provision of this operation.

Sample input String;

```
 1. nf.format(xxx jjhjhsss)
 2. nf.format(xxx ddhgshg kkkdkd)
 3. nf.format(xxx ddhgshg jjhjhsss())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match your pattern with:

```
nf\.format\(.*\)
```

and replace with

```
nf.format(0)
```

See it on http://regex101.com/r/eR0pY8

Note that this regex doesn't check for parentheses balance, the `\)` just matches the last `)` on the line. If you need parentheses balance you need to specify your current working platform, for us to answer.

Comment: thanks it works, by the way how can I handle this one;
"xxx"+ nf.format(hhhhhhhh jjj kkkk) + "xxxx"+ nf.format(hhhhhhhh jjj kkkk) +"yyy"
I need just find the between plus and then replace it.

Comment: Use `[^+]*` instead of `.*` -> so it becomes `nf\.format\([^+]*\)` but note that now you can't have a `+` inside parentheses.

Comment: Also add `\r\n` to the set of unallowed characters so it doesn't match carriage returns and line feeds -> so it becomes `nf\.format\([^+\r\n]*\)`

Comment: If my answer is the correct one, please accept it, by clicking the green tick.

Comment: You're welcome, but... I repeat, If my answer is the correct one, please accept it, by clicking the green tick.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below regex,

```
(nf\.format)\((.*)\)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bS4wX9)

Comment: You do not need parentheses around `.*`, do you? Nor around `nf\.format`

Comment: @Teejay yep. That's the capturing group.